# Spring boot authentication using proprietary cookies as well as HTTP authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I have a web application which uses a proprietary cookie format. I also have a Spring Boot service which needs to interoperate with this existing application.

The application will send an HTTP request setting a `EncryptedLoginToken` cookie value. Inside the Spring Boot application it would be easy to write something like

```
boolean userHasPermission (String permission)
{
    LoginToken token = LoginToken.decrypt(cookies['EncryptedLoginToken']);

    return token.isValid () && token.hasPermission (permission);
}
```

The Spring Boot application has controllers like

```
@PostMapping(value="example/request/path")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('example_permission')")
public ResponseEntity<?> exampleRequest ()
{
   // this will only be called if userHasPermission('example_permission') returns true
}
```

The Spring Boot application currently implements HTTP authentication, and both that method and this method must be supported.

How can I insert `userHasPermission` into Spring boot for a) authenticating users and b) checking `hasAuthority`?

Comment: Write an `AuthenticationFilter` that creates an `Authentication` object based on the `LoginToken` that way you don't need to differentiate in your code and everything is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component that implements `PermissionEvaluator`.

```
@Component
public class DocumentsPermissionEvaluator
 implements PermissionEvaluator {

 @Override
 public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
   Object target,
   Object permission) {
     ...
 }
 @Override
 public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
   Serializable targetId,
   String targetType,
   Object permission) {
     ...
  }
}
```

If you do not have appropriate info in the `authentication` object, you can create a custom filter and custom Authentication where you can store info from cookies, if you need it.

```
 @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#param, 'someType', 'SOME_PERMISSION')")
 public Result doSomething(String param) {
   return ...;
 }
```